# How to translate and scale a view top overlay toolbar?

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have a toolbar and a `RelativeLayout` container defined inside my activity (not in the middle).

I want to define an "expand" operation in which the whole `RelativeLayout` container will **animate to top** exactly above the toolbar.

How can I correctly define an `AnimationSet` (with a `ScaleAnimation` and a `TranslateAnimation`) to succeed that?

*An example of the current state:*

[image: View movement]

*The "Custom View" in the diagram is representing the `RelativeLayout` container I described above.

Comment: What is the parent for Toolbar and RelativeLayout? And what is that custom view in that diagram?

Comment: The parent of all Views is a CoordinatorLayout. I edited my question about the custom view.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use an [AnimationSet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html) it should minimally look something like this :

```
TranslateAnimation translateAnim = new TranslateAnimation(fromX , toX , fromY , toY);
ScaleAnimation scaleAnim = new ScaleAnimation(fromX , toX , fromY , toY);
AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
animSet.addAnimation(translateAnim);
animSet.addAnimation(scaleAnim);
animSet.setFillAfter(true);
animSet.setDuration(...);
```

Of course you have to fill in the values for fromX, toX ... etc.

But you can also use [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) instead of an AnimationSet, which is way less code and really easy to use :

```
relativeLayout.animate()
    .translationY(0) // 0 is top of Y axis
    .scaleX(...)      
    .setDuration(...);
```

This is just to point you in a direction, just fill in the blanks with the values you need, and check the docs for other available methods.

Comment: Yeah. I know how the whole operation works. But I dont know how to find the right `toY` and `toX` coordinates..